# ActivityMain not found

Tags: android, activity

```
<?xml version="1.0.1" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.summer.game">


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.summer.activity_main" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Пытаюсь сделать плеер. Самый простой.
После добавления кода,приложение запустилось,но просто запустилось и не работало(ошибок  не выдало). При открытии  MainActivity выделено синим!
Есть кнопка интернет радио там,так после добавления разрешений доступа в интернет выдало это:

```
NullPointerException: null
20:31:40 Error Report: Submitted
20:32:50 Error running app: Default Activity not found
20:43:49 Error running app: Default Activity not found


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,
    MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
final String LOG_TAG = "myLog";

final String DATA_STREAM = "https://www.radiorecord.ru/player/";
final String DATA_SD = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)
        + "/music.mp3";
final Uri DATA_URI = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,13359);

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
AudioManager audioManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);


}

public void onClickStart (View view) {
    releaseMP();
try{
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.btnSD:
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Start SD");
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(DATA_SD);
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
            break;
        case R.id.btnUri:
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Start Uri");
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(String.valueOf(DATA_URI));
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
            break;


    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if (mediaPlayer == null)
    return;

    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
}

private void releaseMP(){
    if (mediaPlayer != null){
        try{
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    if (mediaPlayer == null)
        return;
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnPause:
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            break;
        case R.id.btnNext:
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() +10000);
            break;
        case R.id.btnBack:
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() -10000);
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onPepared");
    mp.start();

}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCompletion");
    mp.start();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    releaseMP();
}
```

}

```
package com.example.summer.game;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

//Context context;
Intent intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    Thread logoTimer = new Thread(){
        public void run()
        {
            try{
                int logoTimer = 0;
                while (logoTimer < 5000){
                    sleep(100);
                    logoTimer = logoTimer +100;
                }
                startActivity(new Intent("com.tutorial.activity_main"));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                finish();

            }
        }
    };
    logoTimer.start();
}
```

}

Comment: Покажите `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: а можете свой манифест показать? там точно добавлена Активити-лаунчер?

Comment: А если в манифесте все нормально, попробуйте `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...`.

Comment: Расскажите вот про это `приложение запустилось,но просто запустилось и не работало(ошибок не выдало). При открытии MainActivity выделено синим! ` по-подробнее, а то как-то не совсем понятно.

Comment: @post_zeew Так как приложения я только учусь делать,то оно соответственно не доделано. При запуске отображается сначала заставка(SplashActivity), далее MainActuvuty с несколькими кнопками. так при открытии файла MainActivity в классе
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
MainActivity выделена синим.

Comment: @ДмитрийЗенин, Добавьте код обеих активити.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если `MainActivity` совсем не вызывается, то, возможно, дело в том, что, желая ее вызвать, вы указываете неверный `action` у `intent`. Укажите тот, который указан в манифесте или же воспользуйтесь явным интентом.
То есть, попробуйте в `SplashActivity` заменить

`startActivity(new Intent("com.tutorial.activity_main"));`

на

`startActivity(new Intent("com.example.summer.activity_main"));`

или на

`startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));`

Последнее соответствует явному интенту.